# PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Нашёл пример как можно по частям собирать linq запрос. С помощью класса predicateBuilder. Нашёл тему на стеке

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490893/how-does-predicatebuilder-work

Но почему то так же не получается.
Вот мой код:

```
Expression<Func<Cars, bool>> mark;
Expression<Func<Cars, bool>> carModel;
Expression<Func<Cars, bool>> year;
int rYear;
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    mark = c => c.Mark == comboBox1.SelectedItem;
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
    carModel = m => m.CarModel == comboBox2.SelectedItem;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out rYear))
    year = y => y.Equipment.ReleaseYear == rYear;
var filter = mark.And(mark);
```

Так же 1 параметр в методе And, но вылезает ошибка:

> No overload for method 'And' takes 1 arguments

Нашёл пример на msdn что там должно быть 2 параметра, хотя тогда не понимаю как в примере работает с 1 параметром, но с 2 параметрами:

```
var filter = mark.And(mark, carModel);
```

тоже вылезает ошибка:

> Member 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.And(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема, что я делаю не так?
Пример моего кода:

```
Expression<Func<Cars, bool>> filter = c => true;
            int rYear;
            if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                filter = filter.And(c => c.Mark == comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
                filter = filter.And(m => m.CarModel == comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out rYear))
                filter = filter.And(y => y.Equipment.ReleaseYear == rYear);
            List<Cars> cars = db.Cars.Where(filter).ToList();
            FillGrid(cars);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>   Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Mark_2CE17B8870B608BFF2A3C17C9F7989059371DE18CEBDDB94D2AB8CC02E8785D2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Работает фильтр:

```
int tmpValue = 0;
int.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tmpValue);
List<Cars> cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.MarkId == tmpValue).ToList();
```

Не работает фильтр:

```
Expression<Func<Cars, bool>> filter = c => true;
            int tmpValue = 0;
            if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                int.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tmpValue);
                filter = filter.And(c => c.MarkId == tmpValue);
            }
            if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                int.TryParse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tmpValue);
                filter = filter.And(m => m.CarModelId == tmpValue);
            }
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tmpValue))
                filter = filter.And(y => y.Equipment.ReleaseYear == tmpValue);
            List<Cars> cars = db.Cars.Where(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: Где в твоем коде используется `predicateBuilder`? Подключил ли ты эту _библиотеку_? Судя по ошибке - нет, и компилятор думает ты хочешь вызвать статический метод [`Expression.And`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb301748(v=vs.110).aspx) о чем и говорит в ошибке

Comment: @Grundy нет, не подключал, подскажите пожалуйста как точно называется библиотека которую нужно докачать и какой using подключить?

Comment: В вопросе на английском есть [ссылка](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) перейдя по этой ссылке можно найти как использовать PredicateBuilder, и его исходный код. Кроме того, аналогичную библиотеку можно найти в nuget, например: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PredicateBuilder/

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, нашёл исходный код класса и сделал такой же в своём проекте и подключил к нужной форме. Только теперь вот в чём проблема, если expression null тогда вылетает ошибка. Как сделать так что если условие не выполнилось, и нет ни каких фильтров, то вся модель бы просто вытаскивалась.

Comment: @Grundy пример кода в конце вопроса

Comment: просто не добавляй expression если не нужно. сейчас ты создаешь filter в конце, а ты создай его вначале, по умолчанию с каким нибудь `c => true` - то есть всегда возвращать true, и затем в зависимости от условий сразу обновляй его, а не сохраняй во временные переменные

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, сделал так, и если выражения не добавляются то всё норм, но если условия выполняются то вылетает ошибка, пример последнего варианта кода и текст ошибки, в конце вопроса, подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает?

Comment: какого типа поля Mark и CarModel?

Comment: @Grundy `public virtual Mark Mark { get; set; }
        public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }`

Comment: @Grundy там похоже нельзя использовать такие типы, и поэтому я пошёл по айдишникам, но почему то фильтр теперь не работает, не пойму почему выбираю экземпляр из списка, потом фильтрую, айдишник проверяю и по нему ищу, и почему то в список нечего не попадает.

Comment: @Grundy последний пример с использованием id для фильтрации, взгляните пожалуйста, я написал как фильтр работает а как нет, там где работает я просто использую значение комбобокса первого, во втором случае уже пример с фильтрами по всем полям, я там выбираю например так же только значение в первом комбо боксе, но уже лист Cars пустой, хотя одно и то же происходит, только тут я уже использую предикейт билдер, и нечего не работает, подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело?

Comment: используй разные переменные tmpValue, а не одну как сейчас

Comment: @Grundy а какая разница? Я же просто пробую выбрать только марку автомобиля и всё, и даже с 1 фильтром уже не работает

Comment: попробуй использовать вариант из nuget, там немного другая реализация. Ты уверен, что по соответствующему фильтру что-то должно вернуться?

Comment: @Grundy ну ты же видишь, что код один и тот же получается, если я в обоих случаях использую только комбо бокс 1 и в обоих случаях выбираю в нём одно и то же значение.

Comment: @Grundy а на счёт нагета, у меня почему то в нагете нет этой библиотеке, пишу там Predicate, и пусто. У меня 2013 visual sturio, не знаю влияет ли это как то или нет.

Comment: @Grundy попробовал разные переменные и вправду помогло, какая то мистика, создаю переменную прям в самом трай парсе `out int myvariable` и так работает всё.

Comment: Ну и отлично :-) можешь написать ответ, что и как чинил :)

Comment: @Grundy хорошо, как будет свободная минутка, распишу обязательно)